# Не работает ACF в сайдбаре(WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Я использую плагин: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Есть простой **html файл** с названием **sidebar.php.**
В этом файле есть место для вывода картинки через ACF плагин:

```html
<figure class="Sidebar_Block">
<img class="ACF_Img"  src=" <?php the_field('sidebar-latest') ?> ">  // ****** Место для вывода картинки ****** 
</figure>
```

Файл sidebar.php я вызываю в других файлах(home.php, category.php)
через команду:

> get_sidebar();

Вывод картинки ACF работает только на главной странице(home.php)
А в файле **category.php** вывод картинки через ACF не работает.

Вопрос такой:
**Как подключить ACF к category.php и выводить картинку через админку в WordPress?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на то, что вам нужно получить `ID` сайд бара который вы зарегистрировали. Я думаю, что можно поппробовать так: Получить `id` сайд бара и добавить `echo` при выводе поля.

```php
//Получить ID
$id_side_bar = wp_get_sidebar( $id );

<figure class="Sidebar_Block">
   <img class="ACF_Img" src="<?php echo the_field('sidebar-latest', $id_side_bar)?>">
</figure>
```